# How do I get a scipy.csr sparse-matrix as a normal dense matrix without toDense()?

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a problem with sparse matrixes in scipy. I want to use them as a normal matrix but not with todense() function. I m new in this field, I dont know how I can get the same result when I want to multiply the sparse matrix, but without beeing a sparse matrix... I think sparse matrix only used for faster computation, so it should be possible to do this without a sparse matrix:

**sparse_matrix * 5 == sparase_matrix.todense() * 5 == no_sparse_matrix* 5**

```
data = np.ones(5178)
indices   = [34,12,545,23...,25,18,29] Shape:5178L
indptr = np.arange(5178 + 1)

sparse_matrix = sp.csr_matrix((data, indices, indptr), shape = (5178, 3800))
```

Is this correct?
*`sparse_matrix * 5 == sparase_matrix.todense() * 5 == data * 5 ?`*

My goal is to get the same result as when the sparse matrix is multiplied without using a sparse matrix? Is this possible? How can I do this?

---

edit: about my intension:
My problem is that I want to transfer a python code into java and my java libary for linear algeba does not provide sparse matrix operstions.

So I have to do the same in java without sparse matrixes. I was not sure, if I can just use the data array instead of a sparse matrix.

In the original code a sparse matrix is multiplied with an other matrix. 
To transfer that to java I will just multiply the data array of the sparse matrix with the other matrix. Is this correct?

Comment: Why do you not want to use `todense`?

Comment: My problem is that I want to transfer a python code into java and my java libary for linear algeba does not provide sparse matrix operstions. 

So I have to do the same in java without sparse matrixes. I was not sure, if I can just use the data array instead of a sparse matrix. 

In the original code a sparse matrix is multiplied with an other matrix. 
To transfer that to java I will just multiply the data array of the sparse matrix with the other matrix. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you are asking for, but here's my guess.

Let's just experiment with a simple array:

Start with 3 arrays (I took these from another sparse matrix, but that isn't important):

```
In [165]: data
Out[165]: array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11], dtype=int32)

In [166]: indices
Out[166]: array([1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3], dtype=int32)

In [167]: indptr
Out[167]: array([ 0,  3,  7, 11], dtype=int32)

In [168]: M=sparse.csr_matrix((data,indices,indptr),shape=(3,4))
```

These arrays have been assigned to 3 attributes of the new matrix

```
In [169]: M.data
Out[169]: array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11], dtype=int32)

In [170]: M.indices
Out[170]: array([1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3], dtype=int32)

In [171]: M.indptr
Out[171]: array([ 0,  3,  7, 11], dtype=int32)
```

Now try multiplying the `.data` attribute:

```
In [172]: M.data *= 3
```

Low and behold we have multiplied the 'whole' array

```
In [173]: M.A
Out[173]: 
array([[ 0,  3,  6,  9],
       [12, 15, 18, 21],
       [24, 27, 30, 33]], dtype=int32)
```

Of course we can also multiply the matrix directly.  That is, multiplication by a constant is defined for csr sparse matrices:

```
In [174]: M *= 2

In [175]: M.A
Out[175]: 
array([[ 0,  6, 12, 18],
       [24, 30, 36, 42],
       [48, 54, 60, 66]], dtype=int32)

In [176]: M.data
Out[176]: array([ 6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36, 42, 48, 54, 60, 66], dtype=int32)
```

Out of curiousity lets look at the source array.  It too has changed.  So `M.data` points to the same array.  Change one, change the other.

```
In [177]: data
Out[177]: array([ 6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36, 42, 48, 54, 60, 66], dtype=int32)
```

So when the matrix is created this way, it is possible to multiply it by a scalar in several different ways.

Which is best?  Directly multiplying the `.data` attribute might be faster than multiplying the matrix.  But you should be aware of the differences between manipulating `.data` directly, and using the defined math operations for the whole matrix.  For example `M*N` performs matrix multiplication.  You really should understand the matrix data structure before you try changing its internals directly.

The ability to modify `data`, the source array, depends on creating the matrix just this way, and maintaining that pointer link.  If you defined it via a `coo` matrix (or `coo` style inputs), the `data` link would not be maintained.  And `M1 = M*2` is not going to pass this link on to `M1`.

Get your code working with the normal math operations `sparse` has defined. Later, if you still to squeeze out more speed, you can dig into the internals, and streamline selected operations.

Comment: THANK YOU!!! Great post, great explanation! Awesome!
My problem is that I want to transfer a python code into java and my java libary for linear algeba does not provide sparse matrix operstions. So I have to do the same in java without sparse matrixes. I was not sure, if I can just use the data array instead of a sparse matrix, but as you showed me, I can :-) In the original code a sparse matrix is multiplied with an other matrix. To transfer that to java I will just multiply the data array of the sparse matrix with the other matrix. Thank you, your post helped me a lot!

Comment: That only works if you are doing element by element multiplication and the indices match.  Matrix multiplication (np.dot) is much more complicated.  Remember, `.data` contains only the nonzero elements.

Comment: And make sure you understand difference between the `csr` and `coo` formats.